# make_pair like trick for noncopyable classes

Tags: c++, std-pair, noncopyable

make_pair can create pairs without mentioning the types.  I want to use the same trick for my class, but it inherits from boost::noncopyable, so this does not compile:

```
template<class Iter>
struct bit_writer : boost:noncopyable
{
    Iter iter;
    bit_writer(Iter iter)
    : iter(iter)
    {}
};

template<class Iter>
bit_writer<Iter> make_bit_writer(Iter iter)
{
    return bit_writer<Iter>(iter);
}
vector<char> vec;
auto w = make_bit_writer(vec);
```

Any alternative?  I tried making make_bit_writer a friend, and then run out of ideas.

Comment: Assuming you don't want to return via some sort of pointer (preferably a smart pointer), is it possible to make bit_writer a move-only class?  As it is, you're basically telling the compiler to create a temporary and return it, but the temporary can neither be moved nor copied.

Comment: Have you tried macros instead? :-D  (just kidding...)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have C++11 you can do this using something like:

```
#include <functional>
#include <utility>
#include <type_traits>

struct noncopyable_but_still_moveable {
  noncopyable_but_still_moveable(const noncopyable_but_still_moveable&) = delete;
  noncopyable_but_still_moveable(noncopyable_but_still_moveable&&) = default;
  noncopyable_but_still_moveable() = default;
  noncopyable_but_still_moveable& operator=(const noncopyable_but_still_moveable&) = default;
  noncopyable_but_still_moveable& operator=(noncopyable_but_still_moveable&&) = default;
};

template <typename T>
struct test : noncopyable_but_still_moveable {
  test(T) {}
  // the rest is irrelevant 
};

template <typename T>
test<T> make_test(T&& val) {
  return test<typename std::remove_reference<T>::type>(std::forward<T>(val));
}

int main() {
  auto && w = make_test(0);
}
```

Note that I've replaced `boost::noncopyable` with a type that has a deleted copy constructor. This is the C++11 way of making something non-copyable and is needed because the boost class was also not moveable. Of course you could just put that inside the class itself and not inherit any more.

Without C++11 you'll want to use something like [Boost move](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_50_0/doc/html/move.html) to emulate these semantics.

Comment: I changed your last line to

    auto&& w = make_test(0);

so I can call non const members on w.  Is the change safe?

Comment: if w is const I can't call non const members.

Comment: @BrunoMartinez - updated. Turned out my answer was wrong originally. Some input from the C++ chat room helped fix it.

Answer (score 2):

You will need C++11 and to update your class for move semantics. There is no other solution to the proposed problem.

```
class test {
public:
    test(test&&);
    // stuff
};
test make_test(...) {
    return test(...);
}
int main() {
    // Both valid:
    auto p = make_test(...);
    auto&& p2 = make_test(...);
}
```